# What do special palico team attacks do?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

So all palicos have one of three "team attacks":

- Purrtuoso - The palicos heal you and increase your maximum health and
  stamina
- Rath-of-Meow - The palicos jump into a tank and attack the monster with ranged attacks
- Flying F-Bomb - The palicos launch a rocket that staggers the monster and deals damage

...or at least I thought they could only have one of those three.

As I started to recruit palicos from high rank quests, I've noticed some of them have different abilities:

- Purrtuoso/Water
- Rath-of-Mix
- Rath-of-Fast
- (etc)

I'm assuming these abilities are variations on the three "base" ones, but what do they do and is there a full list of them? Their ingame descriptions are identical to those of the base abilities.

Comment: I haven't actually used the Flying F-Bomb one before, but I've heard it does something similar to a flash bomb -- correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation it looks like the names are affected by another skill the palico has.

- "Rath-of-Fast" has a "Team Attack Haste" ability (which increases setup time of team attacks)
- "Purrtuoso/Water" and "Rath-of-Water" have a "Water Synergy" ability (which adds an element to a team attack)
- "Rath-of-Signal" has a "Team Attack Signal" ability (which lets you manually activate the team attack by signalling to your palicos (Start+X))
- "Rath-of-Mix" one has both "Team Attack Boost" (adds "new properties" to team attacks) and "Dragon Synergy", so the "Mix" suffix probably just means the team attack is affected by multiple abilities.

So in other words just looking for their abilities that affect team attacks will explain its name!

Answer (score 1):

How about a complete list?

### **Team Attack+**

Causes Flying F-Bomb to reduce the monster's elemental resistances by 5 for 3 minutes, Wrath-of-Meow to deal 10% more damage, and Purrtuoso to increase Defense by 25 for 3 minutes.

### **Team Attack Boost**

Causes Flying F-Bomb to trip monsters on hit, Wrath-of-Meow to fire 20% stronger shots with a small explosion, and Purrtuoso to keep recovering small amounts of Health over time.

### **Team Attack Haste**

Causes Flying F-Bomb to fly faster, Wrath-of-Meow to fire two shots at once, and Purrtuoso to be performed faster.

### **Element Synergy**

Causes Flying F-Bomb to reduce elemental resistances by 20(!) for 3 minutes, Wrath-of-Meow to deal elemental damage, and Purrtuoso to boost elemental resistances by 30 for 3 minutes.

### **Team Attack Redux**

Causes Flying F-Bomb to immediately retry once if it misses its target, Wrath-of-Meow to immediately retry once if it gets destroyed, and Purrtuoso to immediately retry once if it didn't cause the hunter's health and stamina to max.

Flying M-Bomb, Wrath-of-Mix, and Purrtuoso/Mix all have any two of those skills.

All info from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtx1G.png) and personal experience.

Answer (score -1):

Flying F-Bomb is when both Palicos jump on a rocket and blind a monster by covering its eyes and hitting it in the face. It lasts much longer then a flash bomb but has the same effect.